# Can't make @Get('id') to work in NestJS tutorial

Tags: nestjs

So I am following this tutorial, and following it, word by word:

https://medium.com/@kaushiksamanta23/nest-js-tutorial-series-part-1-introduction-setup-c87ba810ea9e

So I have this in my service file:

```
getCourse(courseId): Promise<any> {
    let id = Number(courseId);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const course = this.courses.find(course => course.id === id);
        if (!course) {
            throw new HttpException('Course does not exist', 404)
        }
        resolve(course);
    });
}
```

and this in my controller, exactly like in the tutorial ,except the log:

```
@Get(':courseId')
async getCourse(@Param('courseId') courseId) {
    console.log(courseId)
    const course = await this.coursesService.getCourse(courseId);
    return course;
}
```

In the POSTMAN, when calling http://localhost:3000/courses/courseId=3, I am getting      "message": "Course does not exist"

The log clearly shows the problem:

```
{ courseId: 'courseId=3' }
```

So when I try http://localhost:3000/courses/3 instead it works, but it's not the right way.

I am lost here, my code is identical to the one in tutorial, and I thought the whole purpose of @Param('courseId') is to recognize the string 'courseId' as key and get whatever value after the '=' in the url. If so, why am I receiving 'courseId=3'?  Surely I am not supposed to parse the string manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing URL Parameters with Query Parameters. In a URL, you can have parameters that are parsed differently depending on the route handler. In this case, your URL says that you have a base of `courses` and then a url parameter by the name `courseId`. When you make the request, the URL looks like`http://localhost/courses/3` (the 3 is the `courseId`) and then you would get the id like `req.param['courseId]`. If you are wanting to use a URL more like `http://localhost/courses/?courseId=3` then you need to use `@Query()` instead to get the query parameter (this would map to `req.query` instead of `req.param`)